# Terminal history in auto-completion

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, history, autocomplete, command-history

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and for some reason there is no terminal history (hitting the up arrow for the previous command), nor is there auto-completion (hitting the tab key). These wonderful features have always worked on any UNIX machine I have used in the past. I looked into the keyboard shorcuts menu for the terminal and did not see anything there.

1. How can I get the up arrow to give me the previous terminal command?
2. How can I get the tab key to perform auto-completion?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Pretty sure I am using `bash`, `echo $SHELL` returns `/bin/sh`. I am running this on my local box. I'm not sure how to run history, but when I do `ls -a` I am not seeing the usual history file (I think it is called .history?)

Comment: Need a bit more info. Are you using `bash`? What does `echo $SHELL` return?  Does running `history` show you the past commands? If tab doesn't work you have probably changed something. Are you `ssh`ing into this machine or is your local box?

Comment: Please check out my edit!

Comment: Awh I thought this was going to be a question about getting completion for words recently printed to the terminal's stdout.  I've always wanted that.  Guess I should ask it.  Although it's a StackOverflow question `iff` no quick solution currently exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using `bash`, you're using `sh`. What that means depends on your system, [on Debian and Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh), `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `dash` so that's what your default shell is. `dash` does not have the functionality you want, you need to switch to another shell like `bash` or `zsh`. You can do this with the command `chsh`:

```
$ chsh
Password: 
 Changing the login shell for terdon
 Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
  Login Shell [/bin/sh]: /bin/bash
```

Now, every new terminal you open will be running `bash` and the up arrow should give you the history.

---

Even on systems where `sh` is a link to `bash`, the two are not equivalent. As explained in `man bash`:

```
   If  bash  is  invoked  with  the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup
   behavior of historical versions of sh as  closely  as  possible,  while
   conforming  to the POSIX standard as well.  When invoked as an interac‐
   tive login shell, or a non-interactive shell with the  --login  option,
   it  first  attempts  to read and execute commands from /etc/profile and
   ~/.profile, in that order.  The  --noprofile  option  may  be  used  to
   inhibit  this  behavior.  When invoked as an interactive shell with the
   name sh, bash looks for the variable ENV, expands its value  if  it  is
   defined,  and uses the expanded value as the name of a file to read and
   execute.  Since a shell invoked as sh does not attempt to read and exe‐
   cute  commands from any other startup files, the --rcfile option has no
   effect.  A non-interactive shell invoked with  the  name  sh  does  not
   attempt  to  read  any  other  startup files.  When invoked as sh, bash
   enters posix mode after the startup files are read.
```

Comment: That appears to work. It looks like I don't have the permissions to change it though...

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus to change what? `chsh` should be run as your normal user and asks for your normal user's password.

Comment: This is what it tells me: chsh: user 'codeking' does not exist in /etc/passwd

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus sounds like your user does not have an entry in the local `/etc/passwd` file, have a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/405478/85695), can you log into a master node? You can also just run `bash` to get a bash shell.